# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

The order of $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ is $24$, and the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ is $24$. However, the two are not isomorphic because $4$ and $6$ are not relatively prime. How, though, to show that there is no bijection?

I think the two would be one-to-one, since the orders are the same. I'm not certain of onto, though. Presumably it's not.

I'm reviewing for my quiz.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a bijection between them because they have the same cardinality; a bijection has nothing to do with the group structure. What you need to show is that there is no *isomorphism* between them.

Hint: suppose there is an isomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$. There is an element $g$ of order $24$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$. What does that say about $\varphi(g)$? (Some [help](https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/group-isomorphisms-preserve-the-order-of-an-element/) if you are stuck.) Why is this a contradiction?

---

Edit: adding some clarification.

Goal: show the two groups are not isomorphic.

This means we need to show that there is no isomorphism (bijective homomorphism) between the two groups.

Dead end: If there is no bijection between the two groups, then indeed we would be finished, since if no bijection exists, certainly no isomorphism exists. (For example, if you wanted to prove that $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are not isomorphic, this is enough.) However, the two groups in your question have the same cardinality so there does exist a bijection. Thus, this simpler approach will not work.

Proof outline: assume that there exists an isomorphism between the two groups, and show that a contradiction arises.

Regarding my hint: there is an element $g$ of order $24$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{24}$. Because $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, $\varphi(g)$ also has order $24$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$. This is a contradiction because $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$ has no element of order $24$.

Comment: An isomorphism is a bijective homomorphism. So don't you mean that I need to show that there is no homomorphism? Also, I thought that a bijection showed that two sets had the same cardinality, not that two sets having the same cardinality showed a bijection between them.

Comment: Also, your hint doesn't help at all. Sorry. I don't get what you're driving at with the element g of order 24.

Comment: He meant isomorphism, since that's what you need to show doesn't exist (if it did, they would be isomorphic!). If the sets have the same cardinality, then the reason that no isomorphism exists would be because there is no bijective homomorphism; there are bijections, and there are homomorphisms, but not both. Also, the definition of two sets having the same cardinality is that there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon Added some clarification

Answer (score 2):

The possible order of element in $\Bbb{Z_4}$ is $1,2,4$.
while the possible order of element in $\Bbb{Z}_6$ is $1,2,3,6$.
Note that the order of $(x,y)\in\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_6$ is $\text{lcm}(|x|,|y|)$.
It can be verified that the maximum possible order of element in that group is $12$.
Hence there does not exist an element of order $24$ in that group.
We conclude $\Bbb{Z}_4\times\Bbb{Z}_6\not\cong\Bbb{Z}_{24}$ since for two groups to be isomorphic, they must have same number of elements with same order.

Answer (score 1):

There certainly is a bijection. What you won't find is a bijective homomorphism. Look for structural differences in the groups. Hint: whether or not a group is cyclic is a property that isomorphic groups will share (the formal vocabulary is that being cyclic is a property that is invariant under isomorphism).